# Perl pack use - double big endian?

Tags: perl, binary, endianness

According to this calculator site ([link text](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?decimal=051)), when converting 3 from decimal to double, I should get `4008 0000 0000 0000`.

When using the Perl [pack](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html#pack-TEMPLATE%2CLIST) function, with the parameter "d>*", I expected to see `4008 0000 0000 0000` as I use this function:

```
print $File pack("d>*", 3);
```

But when I "hexdump" to the Perl output file, I see `0840 0000 0000 0000`.

I thought that it might belong to the big/little endian, but when trying the little endian,

```
print $File pack("d<*", 3);
```

I get this: `0000 0000 0000 4008`

What shall I do if I want to get the result `4008 0000 0000 0000` from Perl `pack` output?

By the way, when using "float" - everything works like it is expected to be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your intuition about the byte order in Perl is correct, but I think that the hexdump output doesn't mean what you think it does. It looks like hexdump is displaying each pair of bytes in a consistent but counterintuitive order. Here are some experiments you can run to get your bearings.

```
# bytes are stored in the order that they are printed
$ perl -e 'print "\x{01}\x{02}\x{03}\x{04}"' | od -c
0000000 001 002 003 004
0000004

# perl reads the bytes in the correct order    
$ perl -e 'print "\x{01}\x{02}\x{03}\x{04}"' | perl -ne 'print map{ord,$"}split//'
1 2 3 4

# but the way  hexdump  displays the bytes is confusing (od -h gives same output)
$ perl -e 'print "\x{01}\x{02}\x{03}\x{04}"' | hexdump
0000000 0201 0403
0000004
```

Comment: Piping into `hex` results in `01 02 03 04`. This is the version from [esr](http://catb.org/esr/software.html), and also in general superior to `hexdump` from util-linux or `xxd`.

Comment: OK, Perl is doing fine. The solution is to add "-C" to Hexdump:
"hexdump -C [FileName]" will show the expected results.